# Downloaded Json File, not Working after Building the Game

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save, loading

**Good Day Community,**

Im Working on a silly drinking game since a few weeks. Its all fine and dandy. Worked my way through all my ideas and got it done. I was pretty proud of my self. Now here´s the kicker. The game downloads a Json file from my Nextcloud using www in Unity. The Json Holds all the Game_Cards. It worked Really well in Unity, But after i build the game, Its just doing nothing. Im pretty Sure im missing something here. But i have no Clue how to Debug it. And to be frank, i think i have Workblindness on this one. I hope its a simple fix.

**What i think is going on Maybe:**

- Download works Fine but Json file is saved to wrong or inaccesible Path
- Download is not Working at all.

**Card Path:**

```
cardPath = Application.dataPath + "/Saves/cards.json";
```

**Download Method**

```
IEnumerator Cards()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest("https://my.link.wich/nobody/should/know");
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            string downloadedText = www.downloadHandler.text;
            File.WriteAllText(cardPath, downloadedText);
            ReadCards();
        }
    }
```

**Reading Cards from Json**

```
public void ReadCards()
    {
        string cardFile = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
        cardDatabase = JsonUtility.FromJson<CardListObject>(cardFile);
    }
```

First time using StackOverflow an actually posting something. Be kind on me :D

**Update**

Got it Working!
I had to create the Folder first.

```
cardPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saves/cards.json";
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saves"))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saves");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In build, you need to use `Application.persistentDataPath` not `Application.dataPath`

UPD: My bad, you are reading only if downloading. So you can ignore next part.

You need to do something in your `ReadCards` method in case the file does not exists, because you can have a download error and file will not be created.

For example:

```
public void ReadCards()
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(cardPath) return;

        string cardFile = File.ReadAllText(cardPath);
        cardDatabase = JsonUtility.FromJson<CardListObject>(cardFile);
    }
```

Then your `cardDatabase` will stay with default values and you will not have a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: I saw the persistentDataPath thingy, but its not working for me. Is it because i create another Folder in there with: `"/Saves/cards.json";` ?

Thanks for the tip with the Download Error.

Comment: @EddieEdson You need to create directory first. Keep in mind, that this method will not create directory, if it already exists, so you don't need additional checking `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saves");` Put it before writing to file.

Comment: Oh my god, you´re my hero. I was looking at my AppData folders and was just thinking the same, and was about to ask you. I try it out and let you know!

Comment: Worked, the only thing is i had to switch back to main menu and restart the "game" part of the game so it could read the file, but thats very minor! thank you so much, i was just blind and could´nt see the folder thing. But i keep in mind to create Folders First and then wirte to them. Lessons Learned! Again, thank you so much! Made my day!